# 'uncommitted work pending' even when all DML statements have been deactivated

Tags: callout, exception, future

Our system is pretty complex with DML statements, call-outs and future methods everywhere. After adding some more functionality, I ran into the dreaded 'uncommitted work pending' error. It had been a while since I saw one of those. I just could not find out what DML caused this error. Attempts to recreate the error via a unit test were unsuccessful: they all run without errors.

Even after disabling all update and insert statements, I still get this error. It happens after the second call-out during a transaction. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling for the error gives lots of suggestions, such as moving the call-out to a future method, or collecting all DMLs and perform them after the call-out.

But I had disabled all DML statements, so that wasn't it. More googling led me to [this](https://www.joelemmer.com/how-to-fix-uncommitted-work-pending-exception/) and [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385708&type=1). And that was the problem: not only DML before a call-out will cause this error, also **calling a future method before a call-out will cause it**.

That also explains why I couldn't reproduce it with a unit test: calls to future methods are handled differently in unit tests compared to using Salesforce interactively.

Comment: Another common DML-like operation that will cause this issue is calling `Database.setSavepoint()`

Comment: @DerekF I never use those, so for me that was not a problem.

Comment: Other people may use them, though, which is why I made a note of it.